# Getting 200 as status code but blank response from api

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Im trying to use nodejs request to request data from an api called keywords everywhere, their documentation didnt have anything for nodejs, but they do have bash so what I did was I converted their bash to a nodejs request. for more context, here's their documentation :
https://api.keywordseverywhere.com/docs/#/keywords/get_keywords_data
My code seems to work because its returning a status code of 200 but the problem is that it returns a blank data:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "credits": 93735,
    "time": 0
}
```

If the request is successful it should return something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "vol": 390,
            "cpc": {
                "currency": "$",
                "value": "5.51"
            },
            "keyword": "keywords tool",
            "competition": 0.33,
            "trend": [
                {
                    "month": "May",
                    "year": 2019,
                    "value": 480
                }]
        },
"credits": 95597600,
    "time": 0.02
}
```

Im guessing there is something wrong with my code since I used a converter and it's not reading the body request properly. Here's my code:

```
var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer (API-KEY-HERE)',
    'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};


var options = {
    url: 'https://api.keywordseverywhere.com/v1/get_keyword_data',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: 'dataSource=gkp&country=us&currency=USD&kw[]=keywords&kw[]=keyword'
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.body)
    
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request.post(options, callback);
```

Comment: consider playing around with the request body data you're sending! Like passing an object

Comment: okay I will try that brb

Comment: I've tried using an object to pass on the body, now its giving me an error of "The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array."

Comment: try adding `response.end()` at the end of your callback function

Comment: it says " response.end is not a function"

Comment: I've tried writing it in postman and the same thing happens, 200 status code but empty data.

Comment: FYI, it would be very rare for any server to respond with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted data. I'd say your `Accept` request header is incorrect here. You probably meant to use `Content-type` instead

Comment: Hello! sorry it was originally written as application/json but I contacted the api's support and thats what they told me to input. I also tried what you said but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code is the body, anyway this is how the code should look like:

```
const request = require('request');
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://api.keywordseverywhere.com/v1/get_keyword_data',
    'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer insertAPIKeyHere'
    },
    formData: {
    'kw[]': 'keyword',
    'country': 'us',
    'currency': 'usd',
    'dataSource': 'gkp'
    }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error){console.log(error)};
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometime debugging a similar issue only to discover that the path i have in the API handler is different than the one I am calling via `ajax` ,I am calling this `/api/v1/togglePhoneState` but in the API handler i am having

```
module.exports = {
  method: "POST",
  path: "/togglePhoneState/{id}",

  ..etc

}
```

updating the API handler path to `/api/v1/togglePhoneState` fixed the issue for me.